# Stroboscope with Arduino

Tags: arduino, encoder

first sorry for my bad english

I'm a student and I want to make a Stroboscope with Arduino for my school project

The frequency is variable between 10hz to 3000 hz and it changes using a rotary encoder

that when normally rotate the encoder 1 step frequency \pm 1hz and when rotate encoder when it pushed down frequency \pm 100hz

and Arduino make a PWM signal on pin 13 and it connect to a high power npn transistor and it turn on and off a 10 watt led

I code it using Encoder.h library by Paul Stoffregen and tone() function

but I have a PROBLEM

I code this program and upload it to Arduino Uno but it doesn't work IDK where is the problem

```
#include <Encoder.h>
#define ENCODER_PULSES_PER_STEP 1
int f = 10;
int direction;
Encoder myEnc(2, 3);
int t = 0;
void setup() {

  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(4, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(2, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(3, INPUT_PULLUP);
  direction = myEnc.read();
}

void loop() {


  if (abs(direction) >= ENCODER_PULSES_PER_STEP) {
    if (direction > 0) {
      if (digitalRead(4) == 1) {
        f++;
        if (f >> 2500)f = 2500;
      }
      else {
        f = f + 100;
        if (f >> 2500)f = 2500;
      }
    } else {
      if (digitalRead(4) == 1) {
        f--;
        if (f << 10)f = 10;
      }
      else {
        f = f - 100;
      }
    }
    myEnc.write(0);


  }
  tone(13, f);
}
```

Comment: don't set pinmode for encoder pins, the library handles it. read the encoder in loop(). and << is a bit shift operator

Comment: You can't use the PWM of the Arduino to create a stroboscope. You will never see what you want, as the PWM is more a dimmer if you connect a lamp or LED (but there are many other programming errors, as Juraj said). If you want a stroboscope, you have to set the pulse as low as possible (`tone()` has a duty cycle of 50% and `analogwrite()` has a fixed frequency). Check this for your stroboscope: https://github.com/PaulStoffregen/TimerOne

Answer (score 1):

When your program starts the function `setup` is executed once.

Then in an infinite loop the function `loop` is executed.

As you have `direction = myEnc.read();` only in `setup` you'll only read the encoder once.

From the Encoder [library's documentation](https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/td_libs_Encoder.html):

```
/* Encoder Library - TwoKnobs Example
 * http://www.pjrc.com/teensy/td_libs_Encoder.html
 *
 * This example code is in the public domain.
 */

#include <Encoder.h>

// Change these pin numbers to the pins connected to your encoder.
//   Best Performance: both pins have interrupt capability
//   Good Performance: only the first pin has interrupt capability
//   Low Performance:  neither pin has interrupt capability
Encoder knobLeft(5, 6);
Encoder knobRight(7, 8);
//   avoid using pins with LEDs attached

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("TwoKnobs Encoder Test:");
}

long positionLeft  = -999;
long positionRight = -999;

void loop() {
  long newLeft, newRight;
  newLeft = knobLeft.read();
  newRight = knobRight.read();
  if (newLeft != positionLeft || newRight != positionRight) {
    Serial.print("Left = ");
    Serial.print(newLeft);
    Serial.print(", Right = ");
    Serial.print(newRight);
    Serial.println();
    positionLeft = newLeft;
    positionRight = newRight;
  }
  // if a character is sent from the serial monitor,
  // reset both back to zero.
  if (Serial.available()) {
    Serial.read();
    Serial.println("Reset both knobs to zero");
    knobLeft.write(0);
    knobRight.write(0);
  }
}
```

Notice the differences between your and their code.

Another more simple example from the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/PaulStoffregen/Encoder/blob/master/examples/Basic/Basic.pde) to satisfy Juraj.

```
/* Encoder Library - Basic Example
 * http://www.pjrc.com/teensy/td_libs_Encoder.html
 *
 * This example code is in the public domain.
 */

#include <Encoder.h>

// Change these two numbers to the pins connected to your encoder.
//   Best Performance: both pins have interrupt capability
//   Good Performance: only the first pin has interrupt capability
//   Low Performance:  neither pin has interrupt capability
Encoder myEnc(5, 6);
//   avoid using pins with LEDs attached

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Basic Encoder Test:");
}

long oldPosition  = -999;

void loop() {
  long newPosition = myEnc.read();
  if (newPosition != oldPosition) {
    oldPosition = newPosition;
    Serial.println(newPosition);
  }
}
```

Also note that `<<` is the binary left shift operator, not the less than operator `<` !

In `if (f << 10)f = 10;` you'll shift f 10 bits to the left. As this results in a number > 0, which is true, this condition will alway be met.

Same for `>>` which is the bitwise right shift operator, not greater then!

Comment: @Juraj I quoted the documentation. That's the how to use example they give.

Comment: but it is irrelevant for the Question

Comment: @Juraj it shows how to use an Encoder and especially that you need to read it in loop, not in setup. I don't get your point. Just because there is a second encoder in the example doesn't make it irrelevant.

Comment: OH yeah u right << is for shifting :)

I try this thank u very much